Post login screen with access code
I have a requirement that user should land on post login screen when i click on link from external application. I have access token of salesforce. Is it possible to land on post login screen. When i tried with access token, it still land on login screen. We have close to 10 links to directly land on post log in screen. could you please suggest solution?
This approach i tried.
https://login.salesforce.com/0058a00000LOzF1AAL url and appending Authorization Bearer [accesstoken].

Be very, very careful here. An access token allows whoever uses it to act as if they are the user that the access token was granted for. If the links you're talking about here are accessible to the public or if you're using something like the "client credentials" flow to get an access token to be used generally, then using an access token is a terrible idea. An experience site would be more appropriate in those cases.

Thanks for sharing your thoughts Derek. To provide more context on our business problem, we are developing a custom iOS app[user must login]. We want users to land on the Salesforce post-login screen, specifically the Experience Cloud screen, when they click on a link.

Use the front door to use an existing session.
https://your_salesforce_domain/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid={session_id}&retURL=%2F0058a00000LOzF1AAL

This will bridge session to the UI, allowing the user to see the record without logging in again.
Note that an access token (bearer token) is a valid Session Id for the purposes of getting in the front door.

Thank you for sharing the solution @sfdcfox. To provide more context on our business problem, we are developing a custom iOS app. We want users to land on the Salesforce post-login screen, specifically the Experience Cloud screen, when they click on a link. I believe this can be achieved using the front door. Your input on this would be much appreciated.

@SB For Digital Experiences, read Use of frontdoor.jsp to Log in to Salesforce and Experience Cloud Site.

how to get community user session id. its working fine with sf user however community user it always redirect to login page. much appreciated for your inputs.
